# How can I add a linux folder to a Windows DFS tree?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-server-2008, cifs, dfs

Accessing a Windows DFS share from Ubuntu or any other Linux for that matter, is pretty straight forward. However doing it in reverse seems to be not documented.

I have DFS Namespace running on Windows Server 2008. I would like to add a folder that is hosted on an Ubuntu 13.04 Server box to the DFS namespace. Any recommendations on how to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

It was not has difficult as I thought. I just had to configure the share in samba correctly. Once it showed up DFS could find it easily.

Comment: Using NFS in the Ubuntu box (and in the Windows one, FWIW) might give you better performance.